# How to pass argument to subprocess using gksudo?

Tags: python, subprocess

**Data of FirstFile.py**

```
a=raw_input("Anything")
p=subprocess.Popen(['gksudo','python','file1.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(a)<br>
#some related codes
```

**Data of file1.py**

```
pro=sys.stdin.read()<br>
sys.stdout.write('received data %s' %pro)<br>
```

file1.py gives the output: "**received data**"
It does not show the actual data received.
When I make use of only 'sudo' instead of 'gksudo' it works absolutely fine.
Please suggest how it can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Because,

`gksudo` is used to run graphical (GUI) applications as root and `sudo` is used to run command line applications as root. Here you using command line application. So you have to use `sudo`.

Comment: here I am making use of GUI entities(pygtk). That is why i have asked for gksudo. I need exactly how it works with gksudo. Thank you.@Rahul K P